# How to copy rows from a sheet to another in Excel

Tags: ms-office

I would like to ask for an excel formula for the following scenario:
Example: 
(In Sheet 1, we have these data

```
Column A |  Column B |

123      |     hi    |

345      |    hello  |

123      |    hello  |
```

)
What I want is to copy rows with cell value of "123"  to Sheet 2 after entering a specific value in a box like this

(Sheet 2...

Enter value : 123 <- assume I typed "123"

Result :

```
123  |   hi   |

123  |  hello |
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I found one link on Google regarding your problem try the link if you able to follow it then good otherwise comment here for explanation.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcLNWvhaUH8